# Downloading an mp4 file using javascript

Tags: javascript, download, mp4, mime

How do I allow users to download `mp4` files from a different server that isn't owened by me? No approach I've come across has worked so far. Here's what I've tried:

- The `download` attribute for `a` tags: `<a href="http://example.com/bar.mp4" download="foo.mp4">Download</a>` - not working for me (as in - the attribute doesn't have an effect. Tested in Google Chrome)
- Place a hidden `<iframe>` on the page - doesn't work either since I can't change the MIME-type, the video simply gets played back
- Download using `ajax` - not a good solution as well, since this loads the entire file into the user's RAM. Some videofiles are 1GB+.

Is there any other method? Thanks!

Comment: The browser will choose to download or stream based on http headers, Since you don't control the http server, you cant control the headers.

Comment: @szatmary that's not the case with images or pdfs, why with mp4?

Comment: because your browser has decoders and start playing it instead downloading it. You have to make server script that changes the headers to trigger download instead. You can zip it and it will become "downloadable", but i'm not sure this is ok for you.

Comment: the download attribute is literally there to make what you want to do work, so can you explain what happens instead? "not working for me" doesn't tell us anything about what you actually saw happening, based on which actual code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans "not working" means that the attribute has no effect, it's as if it wasn't there. I'm using normal Chrome on Linux.

Comment: @bksi Yes, I see that it starts playing it. I'd like to download it. I don't have access to the server. Is this not possible?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is not possible to change server headers without access to the server. You can make a proxy that gets the content from this server where you can manipulate the headers.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but some files are 1GB+, so that's not really an option either. Thanks. Btw, how do you know that? Do you have a link or smt?